# COUNTIF and IF to return value

Tags: excel, validation, if-statement, countif, array-formulas

Example Data Picture:

[image: Thanks]

Basically associates use two different systems to log calls and there is a scenario where the same call is logged on two different systems. It gives a unique ID for each call, so perceived two be two calls instead of one. I need to be able to match these up and present as one call.

Data being used and to look up.

```
Call ID
Unique Client ID
Date
```

The `System` is the field I need to return the value for - above is a dummy result I would ideally like.

As you can see from the picture for Client 'ABC' there have been two entries on same day with different Call IDs, so I would want to show different systems have been used, for the other entries they are 'purely' unique so show 1 system.

I have tried COUNTIFS with date logic but can't get anything to work or come close.

This is only one part to the formula as I would then need to go onto checking time of call validations as well but that's for another time.

What I really need - which would work better - would be if Client ID is duplicated on Same Day then show True - If not show false?

Comment: Your picture disappeared

Comment: @pnuts Answer below is correct

Answer (score 1):

> if Client ID is duplicated on Same Day then show True - If not show false

Please try in D2 and copied down to suit:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,C2,B:B,B2)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your picture, but from your description;

If you have Call ID Unique in Column A and Call ID Date in Column B, assuming your data is contained in rows 2 to 50, place this function in cell C2 and drag down, if the function finds any duplicates, the count will be increased from 1 to the number of duplicates found in the list:

```
=IF(AVERAGEIF($B$2:$B$50,B2,$A$2:$A$50)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$50,B2)<>AVERAGEIF($B$2:$B$50,B2,$A$2:$A$50),COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2),1)
```

Then you can just filter out anything that's not a 1

**Edit** If you want to change the outputs to True or False, just do the following instead:

```
=IF(AVERAGEIF($B$2:$B$50,B2,$A$2:$A$50)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$50,B2)<>AVERAGEIF($B$2:$B$50,B2,$A$2:$A$50),TRUE,FALSE)
```

However, this will flag all occurrences of the calls as True, if you want just the duplicates to be flagged, it would be:

```
=IF(AVERAGEIF($B$2:$B$50,B2,$A$2:$A$50)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$50,B2)<>AVERAGEIF($B$2:$B$50,B2,$A$2:$A$50),IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,B2,$A$2:A2,A2)>1,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it half works, what I really need - which would work better - would be if Client ID is duplicated on Same Day then show True - If not show false??? Thanks

Comment: @pnuts Correct, I do enjoy it when the criteria changes every time. Your answer is correct.